# Best practice: Files/Folders permission/owner in symfony2

Tags: apache, security, symfony, permissions, web-deployment

The symfony2's kernel needs to write in the cache ( as the http user ). I also need to read/write into the folder for these reasons:

1. The IDE needs to read/write/create in document root
2. In shell my user should be able to generate bundles and clear the cache
3. My user should be able to manipulate the .git folder ( by staging and commits )
4. I am pushing to the remote/production server and this should be done by my user

What is the best practice for setting the ownership and permissions to document root and files under it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for permission you can read this http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

ACL are a good ways to allow your user and the web server user to manage files on your filesystem.

To deploy your application you can use http://capifony.org

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ACL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) for this.
Let's say your user is `arsham` and apache group is `www-data`

Create a folder to hold document roots for all the applications you develop

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/vhosts
sudo chown arsham:www-data  /var/vhosts
```

Next we set up rwx permission for both the user and a group + SGID bit so that new files and folders will follow the parent directory group.

```
sudo chmod 770 /var/vhosts
sudo chmod g+s /var/vhosts
```

Next we set up default permissions for new files via ACL

```
sudo setfacl -dm u::rwx /var/vhosts
sudo setfacl -dm g::rwx /var/vhosts
sudo setfacl -dm u:arsham:rwx /var/vhosts
sudo setfacl -dm g:www-data:rwx /var/vhosts
sudo setfacl -m u:arsham:rwx /var/vhosts
sudo setfacl -m g:www-data:rwx /var/vhosts
```

Now, you just create the document root for the new project:

```
cd /var/vhosts && mkdir newproject
```

Note that if you need to modify the permissions of already existing files,
you would need to run `setfacl` and `chmod` with -R (recursive) option inlcuded